# Getting cumulative sum for rows (groups)

Tags: jasper-reports

Imagine the following data set:

[image: Cumulative data set]

What's the proper way to get the values of *`TOTAL_CUMULATIVE`* in JasperReports?
i.e: in *"VW"* row it should sum all values (`COST - EXPENSE`) until *"VW"*, which means: (500 - 150) + (400-200) = 550.

column xml code:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement x="746" y="0" width="65" height="13"/>
        <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{BALANCE_BY_ACCOUNTING}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The variable:

```
<variable name="BALANCE_BY_ACCOUNTING" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="groupByAccounting" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost} - $F{expense}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

In the *"VW"* row, the code sets `TOTAL_CUMULATIVE` column value to: 200. It should not. It should set to the cumulative sum 550. The same applies to the other rows. In *"MERCEDES"* row it sets value 600 (should be 11500) and so on.

Comment: By sum I mean, how to show total_cumulative in each row summed?

Comment: Are you using grouping?

Comment: Yes I'm grouping. In that case I'll set reset type to group in the variable summing. But I fail to receive the correct sum in each row. I am creating a variable named $V{TOTAL_CUMULATIVE} which has expression $F{cost} - $F{EXPENSE} and calculation Sum

Comment: I'm not looking for total sum of all records. I want in each row total_cumulative to be sum of cost - expense until the specific row

Comment: I'm not looking for such thing. I want to obtain the values cumulative in each row

Comment: Edited. Included the jrxml

Answer (score 2):

For getting the cumulative sum the simple sum without resering value for every new enrty in Group can be used.

### Example

The Group by *car* field will help us to solve the task and two types of variables:

1. First one for calculating sums for Group (*`resetType="Group" resetGroup="carGroup"`*)
2. Second one for calculating cumulative sum (*`resetType=Report`*)

All data will be placed at *groupFooter* band.

For getting valid results the data should be ordered by *car*.

#### Datasource

The using of simple *csv* datasource is enough for this example.

```
car,cost,expense
BMW,200,50
BMW,100,50
BMW,200,50
VW,200,100
VW,200,100
MERCEDES,200,50
MERCEDES,500,50
```

The name of data adapter for this datasource in the example below is *cars.csv*. The first line from the file is skipped - it is contains the column's name.

#### Report template

The variable we need to show cumulative sum is:

```
<variable name="total" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost} - $F{expense}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

The *textField* with `$V{total}` expression is placed in *groupFooter*.

The *jrxml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Grouping, sum" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" >
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="cars.csv"/>
    <field name="car" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="cost" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="expense" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="costForCar" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="carGroup" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="expenseForCar" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="carGroup" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{expense}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="totalForCar" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="carGroup" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost} - $F{expense}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="total" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Report" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost} - $F{expense}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="carGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{car}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="15">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15" />
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{car}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="110" height="15" />
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{costForCar}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="210" y="0" width="110" height="15" />
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{expenseForCar}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="320" y="0" width="110" height="15" />
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{totalForCar}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="430" y="0" width="110" height="15" />
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{total}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Car]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="110" height="15" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Cost]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="210" y="0" width="110" height="15" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Expense]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="320" y="0" width="110" height="15" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="430" y="0" width="110" height="15" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total, cumulative]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

The same effect can be achieved with help of *Detail* band and *evaluationTime* attribute of *textField* element.

#### Output result

The result in *Jaspersoft Studio (JSS)*:

[image: The result in JSS]